# C++ version highlighting

Tags: c++, version, highlight

Is there a tool or plugin that one could use to tell

1. What c++ version is needed to compile the source files.
2. Let you highlight only the parts of the code that belongs to a certain c++ version.

Use case, I have a library that uses C++11, 14 and 17. I need to back port it to C++11. Hence I want to easily find what parts of the library I need to rework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about tool. But you can go with a kind of elimination process.. Use command line flags for specific version of c++.

**For example when using GCC**

First compile your working source code with option `-std=c++14`. Then you can find all c++17 errors.

After fixing all c++17 errors next compile with option `-std=c++11`. You can find all c++14 errors.

Look into below link for overview.

https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html